# Horizontally concatenate column vectors

Tags: matlab, vector

I have two vectors in MATLAB:

```
a = [1; 2; 3]
b = [4; 5; 6; 7]
```

I want to create a vector `c` as shown below, but I can't figure out how to do it.

```
c = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
```

Comment: c = [a b] and you're good to go

Comment: What you're doing is known as *concatenation*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not sure whether your input vectors are vertical or not, use this robust way:

```
c = [ a(:); b(:) ];
```

The [**`colon`**](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/ref/colon.html) will make a column vector out of every vector, row AND column vectors. So you can concatenate them by `[ ... ; ... ]`. If you want a row vector at the end, you need to [**`transpose`**](https://www.google.com/#q=matlab+transpose) the final result:

```
c = [ a(:); b(:) ].';
```

Comment: thank you very much but maybe my question was not clear or wrong, c = [ a b ] does not work because my vectors are vertical, I tried with horizontal ones and of course it does...should I transpose my vectors? or...probably there is a way to do the concatenation also with vertical vectors. thanks a lot again :-)

Comment: Typo: I guess you mean `;`..? =) But yes, this is definitely more robust.

Comment: @eligioiannetti does it not work? (maybe consider my last edit.)

Comment: horizzontal vectors: c =[a b]
vertical vectors: c=[a ; b]
work perfectly. many thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Simple, just use c = [ a b ] should give you c = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7]